# Is VB.Net Roslyn scripting available?

Tags: .net, vb.net, scripting, roslyn

I was trying to implement the scripting compiler from Roslyn in VB.Net to parse a
piece of string and evaluate the condition using as I said Roslyn this but
I wasn't able to find the correct package inside Nuget. [I found the specified file
in github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Scripting/VisualBasic/VisualBasicScript.vb) with the class that I need to implement this, but I couldn't
track it inside what package was it released.

I tried installing these packages:

```
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" version="3.8.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net472" developmentDependency="true" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" version="3.8.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" version="3.8.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting" version="3.8.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" version="3.8.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting" version="3.8.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Common" version="3.8.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic" version="3.8.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces" version="3.8.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common" version="3.8.0" targetFramework="net472" />
```

With none of those I wasn't able to resolve this piece of code
This is CSharp code, but I want to parse it into VB.Net:

```
public class Globals
{
    public int X;

    public int Y;
}

//..

var globals = new Globals { X = 5, Y = 3 };
// expression now depends on the input (true in this case)
bool result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<bool>(
    "X > Y",
    ScriptOptions.Default,
    globals);
```

Anyone knows if this is currently supported in VB.Net? I believe the project still functional because the file that I referenced before with last modified date January 22th 2020.

I'll appreciate any help into this,
Thank you all

**Update**

What I'm trying to do is to implement a kinda of CQRS pattern and this feature in Roslyn would be pretty useful to implement something like this:

```
Public Class Customer

  Private ID As String
  Private Name As String
  Private Telephone As String

End Class

Public Class ExpressionsCQRS

   Public Function GetFilter(name As String, tel As String) As IEnumerable

      Dim filter As String = $"Function(Of ctm As Customer) Return ctm.Name = '{name}' AndAlso ctm.Telephone = '{tel}'"
      Dim options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(GetType(Customer).Assembly)

      ' The C# code what I took for example says:
      ' Func<Album, bool> discountFilterExpression = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<Func<Album, bool>>(discountFilter, options);
      Dim filterExpression As Func(Of Customer, Boolean) = Await MissingVBScriptReference.EvaluateAsync(Of Func(Of Customer, Boolean))(filter, options)

      Dim query = Me.DbSet(Of Customers).Where(filterExpression)
      Return query

    End Function
End Class
```

**UPDATE** February 28th 2021

I was researching and I couldn't find a possible solution through VB.net. After several updates of packages in my solution and web-searching, finally I decided to use the static C# method and create the lambda with C# and It works. It is a valid workaround if any found this updted note helpful.

Comment: "This is CSharp code, but I want to parse it into VB.Net:" - please elaborate on what you're trying to do.

Comment: "the file that I referenced before with last modified date January 22th 2020" - no, that just means you ran a NuGet package restore on that date. The only date that matters is the one on the NuGet package page.

Comment: Thank your for your response @Dai, What I means that that file has updated. I know that only matters it he nuget package. It is the main goal of my question, identify what it is the package. I assume if the file is updated, may be it is deployed because is used. I will update the question with what I'm trying to do.